# How to change size of a buffer

Tags: c++, memory, locking, buffer

I've been given this code to analyze, and I have to find a way a lock and lock free version of it change the maximum storage of its buffer.

How many elements can be stored, as maximum, in a locked_buffer created with size_ == 100?

I strongly guess the answer is either 100. Or possibly infinity, if old elements can be overwritten. Or maybe it has something to do with memory? I've been studying the code below for a few hours, but I can't find anything that suggest size is being limited or increased.

```
#ifndef LOCKEDBUFFER_H
#define LOCKEDBUFFER_H

#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <atomic>

#include "optional.h"

template <typename T>
class locked_buffer {
public:
  // Creates buffer of size n
  locked_buffer(int n) :
    size_{n},
    buf_{new optional<T>[size_]}
  {
  }

  // Remove copy constructor
  locked_buffer(const locked_buffer &) = delete;

  // Destructor (default generated)
  ~locked_buffer() = default;

  // Gets buffer size
  int size() const noexcept {
    return size_;
  }

  // Checks if buffer is empty
  bool empty() const noexcept {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{mut_};
    return is_empty();
  }

  // Checks if buffer is full
  bool full() const noexcept {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{mut_};
    return is_full();
  }

  // Put an optional value in the queue
  void put(const optional<T> & x);

  // Get a value from the queue
  optional<T> get();

private:
  // Next circular position to position p
  int next_position(int p) const noexcept {
    return p + ((p+1>=size_)?(1-size_):1);
  }

  // Check if buffer is empty without locking
  bool is_empty() const noexcept {
    return (next_read_ == next_write_);
  }

  // Check if buffer is full without locking
  bool is_full() const noexcept {
    const int next = next_position(next_write_);
    return next == next_read_;
  }

private:
  const int size_;
  const std::unique_ptr<optional<T>[]> buf_;
  int next_read_ = 0;
  int next_write_ = 0;

  mutable std::mutex mut_;
  std::condition_variable not_full_;
  std::condition_variable not_empty_;
};


template <typename T>
void locked_buffer<T>::put(const optional<T> & x) 
{
  using namespace std;
  unique_lock<mutex> l{mut_};
  not_full_.wait(l, [this] { return !is_full(); });
  buf_[next_write_] = x;
  next_write_ = next_position(next_write_);
  not_empty_.notify_one();
}

template <typename T>
optional<T> locked_buffer<T>::get()
{
  using namespace std;
  unique_lock<mutex> l{mut_};
  not_empty_.wait(l, [this] { return !is_empty(); });
  auto res = buf_[next_read_];
  next_read_ = next_position(next_read_);
  not_full_.notify_one();
  return res;
}

#endif
```

Comment: Use some container that can easily be resized? Like a `std::vector`?

Comment: It's called a ring buffer.  I suggest you look up how that works before starting work on this.